# C# Selenium Firefox NullReferenceException WebDriverException

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've just rebuilt my development machine and I'm now having issues running Selenium tests.  I know there's an issue with my setup as when I push new code and tests to the build server, they pass without problem.  The tests used to pass without problem before the rebuild on this machine too.  I've reduced my test case to the simplest possible in order to try and isolate the error.

- Firefox: 21.0 (Also produces the same behaviour with Firefox 22.0 & 23.0)
- NuGet packages: Selenium.WebDriver 2.40.0 & Selenium.Support 2.40.0
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

My site test site is a local ASP.NET MVC site and responds to requests in less than 200ms.

My simple failing case is as follows, attempting to login:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        try
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://test.mysite.com/Account/Login/");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("UserName")).SendKeys("AdminUser");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("Password")).SendKeys("AdminPassword");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("log-in-btn")).Click();
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesn't always fail and it doesn't always fail in the same place.  Some runs all the commands will execute.  At other times any of the FindElement lines will fail with the following errors:

NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)

WebDriverException The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL `http://localhost:7055/hub/session/eff6f0c7-84e1-451d-adc8-1f02324d08ae/element` timed out after 60 seconds. at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)

Even when the test raises one of the above errors after a while sat there doing nothing the test browser remains responsive and one can manually complete the tests.

I'm really tearing my hair out over this.  In the past couple of days I've tried many different combinations, e.g. different Firefox versions, switching to Chrome, switching back to Selenium.WebDriver 2.39.0 all with the same results.

I realise this is quite a popular error for Selenium but I'm hoping this simple test case may assist in tracking down what's causing this specific version of it.

Comment: Your sleeps won't help. Also, would be useful to try it in another browser and have an actual test case we can all try too.

Comment: @Arran It fails whether there are sleeps or not.  As mentioned above I'm also in the same situation with the Chrome driver.

Comment: @GilesRoberts - Do you have antivirus/firewall/UAC turned on? In the off chance that these might be interfering, can you turn them off and then try?

Comment: @Faiz Oh you beauty.  I'd switched off the firewall previously in my investigations but as soon as I'd switched off the antivirus everything started working consistently.  For the curious I was running Microsoft Security Essentials and I went into Settings | Real-time protection and unchecked Turn on real-time protection.  Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.  Obviously I'll have to revisit my anti virus.

Comment: @Faiz Which is kind of odd thinking about it as I was using Microsoft Security Essentials before my rebuild and everything was working fine.

Comment: @GilesRoberts - done :) glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver communicates with the browser using JSON over HTTP, and since antivirus/anti-malware programs usually "hook" into browsers, they may inadvertently interfere or block valid traffic also.

Turning off antivirus and firewall programs during testing or in test environments can help resolve such issues.